# Could you explain why is in attach code below the syntax error?

Tags: sql, forms, if-statement, ms-access, syntax-error

Could you explain why is in attach code below the syntax error?

```
If Me.DateBeign <> "" And Me.DateEnd <> "" Then 
q = "SELECT * FROM Controls WHERE [Begin dates of control] = # " & Me.DateBegin & " # AND [End dates of controls ] = # " & Me.DateEnd & " # "
    Me.RecordSource = q
End If
```

Comment: Why are you making us guess what the error is?

Comment: Include the error message!

Comment: First was run-time error: 3075 connect with date format, the was 2465 and it says that it can't find some field, that this query doesn't concern

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the likely misspelled control name, try this full syntax:

```vb
If Not IsNull(Me!DateBegin.Value + Me!DateEnd.Value) Then 
    q = "SELECT * FROM Controls WHERE [Begin dates of control] = #" & Format(Me!DateBegin.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND [End dates of control] = #" & Format(Me!DateEnd.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    Me.RecordSource = q
End If
```

Also, make you the *Format* properties of the two textboxes have been assigned a *Date* format.

Comment: I'm not sur with this solve. Watching in such the same questions in this forum, I'm thinking the problem is connecting all " sings with '

On the other hand: how to assign a date format for textboxes in access VBA (where I need to put this code)

Comment: It will work if your date fields are of data type _DateTime_. If not (Text), modify that, as dates never should be stored as text.

Comment: So I put here DateValue(Me.Text28). But Now I'm testing a version from different forum

Comment: At best, it won't add nothing; at worst, trouble. And what is `Me.Text28`? However, if `[Begin dates of control]` is _Text_, either modify it to hold _DateTime_, or (temporarily) convert to Date: `DateValue([Begin dates of control])`.

Comment: textx28 is a name of TextBox in which I put the Begin dates, which I convent to date type. Form another forum I find that the problem appears in last "#". The run-time error number 3075 appears in case of not finding this sign with double-quote in it.

Comment: This is confusing. `Me.DateBegin` and `Me.DateEnd` were the controls for this according to your question.